# Invariant Violation: Error while using React-Dom renderToString() in es6 importing

Tags: reactjs, express, es6-modules, server-side-rendering, react-dom-server

This question is quite different as I searched a lot for similar but didnt find any I am creating a project of react server side rendering feature and using webpack to write the `es6` code and babel to compile the `jsx` . In my express route I want to convert the `App` component to string and then want to pass to the static html part . it is working fine when I am doing like this

```
  var App = renderToString(<h1> Working Fine now </h1>);
```

but now when I want the App component to be here its not working

```
var App = renderToString(<App />); // Not working
```

I am importing App component in express server like this

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOMServer , {renderToString} from "react-dom/server";
    import  App  from '../common/component/App.js';
```

My App.js

```
import React from "react"

 export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>From COmponent</h1>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

error

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

I checked some issues in Github too but there they were recommending to move to react-0.14 as those issues were old but now I am using react 16

Comment: Which version of Node do you use?

Comment: Try to replace `import  App  from '../common/component/App.js';` by `const App = require('../common/component/App.js').default;`

Comment: will `require` work with es6 exporting?

Comment: yeah did that...still not working

Comment: @Nosyara node version : v8.11.2

Comment: Try var MyApp=renderToString(<App/>)

Comment: I dont know how I missed this error . thank you so much for this @VivekN . You can put that in answer I will appreciate that

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you are already importing App at `Line No 3`

`import  App  from '../common/component/App.js';`

So, to fix your issues just replace this line

`var App = renderToString(<App />); // Not working`

with this

`let MyApp = renderToString(<App />); // Working`